# When one DC crashes, TFS 2012 stops working

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller, team-foundation-server

We have two Windows 2008 domain controllers. We installed the second DC only a few months ago. We also have a TFS 2012 server on the network.

Today, when the older DC crashed, TFS stopped working completely. Local users received messages such as "You are not authorized to access ServerName\Collection". Remote users received messages such as "The server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable".

So my question is, why did TFS not use the second, newer DC instead of just crashing along with the first DC?

Comment: Good question. This kind of thing would really make me angry. Are both DCs global catalogs?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, both DC's are indeed Global Catalogs.

Comment: Are both DC's also DNS servers? If so, is the TFS server configured to use both DC's for DNS?

Comment: brilliant :) TFS only had one DC as a DNS server. I changed it now and will have to test to make sure, but I think you're right. if you want to actually answer, i'll select yours as the correct one

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the TFS server is configured to use both of your DC/DNS servers for DNS.